# What is exact difference between Inheritance and Abstract class?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, abstract-class, abstraction

I know the fundamentals of OOP concepts[Inheritance, Abstraction, Encapsulation, Polymorphism]

We use **Inheritance** in case of Parent-Child relationship[Child can have all functionalities which Parent have and can add more functionality to itself too]

And we use **Abstract class**(In java) for a partial set of default implementations of methods in a class, which also can be implemented by simple Inheritance.

Look below example which makes my point clear.

**Inheritance:**

*Parent class*

```
public class Parent {

    // This method will remain same for all child classes.No need to override
    public void abc() {
        System.out.println("Parent here");
    }

    // This methods need to be overridden from child class
    public int getROI() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

*Child class*

```
public class Child extends Parent{

    @Override
    public int getROI(){
        return 5;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child child =new Child();
        child.abc();
        System.out.println(child.getROI());
    }
}
```

**Abstract Class:**

*Parent class*

```
abstract class Parent {

    // This method will remain same for all child classes.No need to override
    public void abc() {
        System.out.println("Parent here");
    }

    // This methods need to be implemented from child class
    public abstract int getROI();
}
```

*Child class*

```
public class Child extends Parent{

    public int getROI(){
        return 5;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child child =new Child();
        child.abc();
        System.out.println(child.getROI());
    }
}
```

For above programs o/p will be same.

```
O/P:    
Parent here
5
```

So I think,

**Inheritance:** We need to override the method in child class

**Abstract class:** Put abstract keyword in method name and need to implement the method in child class

So Inheritance and abstract class is same *regardless of abstract keyword*

So we can implement abstract class using inheritance, here just method signature change classes(That's my belief).

Is there any significant difference?

Comment: That's right sorry I forgot to mention Abstract class, here I am taking about the major difference between abstract class and inheritance

Answer (score 14):

**Inheritance** is for inheriting properties and having some of its own as well.

**Abstract** is to restrict from being instantiated.

**Example:**
Lets take Vehicle and VehiclePart. But Vehicle as such is very abstract and not complete. So we want Vehicle class abstract because we don't want to instantiate it directly. Car is more meaningful entity than Vehicle and car is a Vehicle. So car extends vehicle and it is not abstract.

```
abstract class Vehicle{
    String name;
}

abstract class VehiclePart{
    String name;
    Date expiry;
}

class Car extends Vehicle{
     List<VehicleParts> parts;
}

class RacingCar extends Vehicle{

}

class Gear extends VehiclePart{
   int numOfGears;
}
```

> Inheritance: We need to override the method in child class

Nope. in the above example you can see Car is inheriting properties like name from Vehicle. Overriding is optional. Like RacingCar can override methods of Car and make it a little bit custom. But basically it is getting(inheriting) some properties from base class. Like all the basic properties of a car will in Car and not in RacingCar. RacingCar will have properties specific to it.

> Abstract class: Put abstract keyword in method name and need to
> implement the method in child class

Nope. It is just to restrict its instantiation. Eg. We don't want to instantiate Vehicle object because there is no meaning to it. A vehicle has to be something like car, bus etc etc. It can't just be a vehicle. So we put abstract and restrict instantiation.

Answer (score 3):

After java 8 you can have static and default methods in Interface. So it makes the interface much similar to abstract class.

***But Still abstract class is class so we can have constructor, instance variable,
getter and setter to change the state of objects. These all functionalities not provided by interface .That is main difference between interface and abstract class after java 8.***

Answer (score 1):

With inheritance you don't need to override a method. Without overriding `getROI` in `Child` you could still call `new Child().getROI()` and get `0` as response.

If on the other hand a method is abstract, it will need to be implemented by the child as there is no default implementation.

Answer (score 1):

An abstract class means you can't instantiate it directly.

```
new Parent()
```

is not allowed.

An abstract method will need to be implemented in an extended class.

Answer (score 1):

**Abstract Class:**

- Abstraction hides the implementation details and shows only the functionality to the user.
- Abstraction helps to reduce the complexity of the code.
- We can't create objects of an abstract class.

**Inheritance:**

- Inheritance is the methodology of creating a new class using the properties and methods of an existing class.
- Inheritance helps to improve code reusability.
- We can create the object of the parent class.

Answer (score 0):

These are two different concept and selections are based on the requirements.

**Abstraction** hide the implementation details and only show the functionality. It reduce the code complexity. **Inheritance** create a class using a properties of another class. It improve the code reusability.

So these are two different things for different purposes.

If this is about the implementation(coding), obviously there are differences than putting abstract keyword in the method name.

- Can't implement method body in abstract methods in abstract class. But can implement method body in methods in parent class.
- In inheritance, child class inherits is parents methods. Same as in abstraction also child class inherits non-abstracts methods of parent class as they are. But child class must implement all the abstract methods in parent class, otherwise child class need to be declared as abstract.
- Can't create instance of abstract class.